# Incompatible pointer type error while setting directives in Apache server

Tags: c++, c, apache, pointers, apache2

I am trying to set a directive in Apache server using the example code in the section 'The directive handler function' at 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html.

Here's my code:

```
static const command_rec example_directives[] =
{
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("exampleEnabled", example_set_enabled, NULL, ACCESS_CONF, "Enable or disable mod_privet"),
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("examplePath", example_set_path, NULL, ACCESS_CONF, "The path to whatever"),
    AP_INIT_TAKE2("exampleAction", example_set_action, NULL, ACCESS_CONF, "Special action value!"),
    { NULL }
};

Handler for directives:


/* Handler for the "exampleEnabled" directive */
const char *example_set_enabled(cmd_parms *cmd, void *cfg, const char *arg)
{
    if(!strcasecmp(arg, "on")) config.enabled = 1;
    else config.enabled = 0;
    return NULL;
}

/* Handler for the "examplePath" directive */
const char *example_set_path(cmd_parms *cmd, void *cfg, char *arg)
{
    config.path = arg;
    return NULL;
}

/* Handler for the "exampleAction" directive */
/* Let's pretend this one takes one argument (file or db), and a second (deny or allow), */
/* and we store it in a bit-wise manner. */
const char *example_set_action(cmd_parms *cmd, void *cfg, const char *arg1, const char *arg2)
{
    if(!strcasecmp(arg1, "file")) config.typeOfAction = 0x01;
    else config.typeOfAction = 0x02;

    if(!strcasecmp(arg2, "deny")) config.typeOfAction += 0x10;
    else config.typeOfAction += 0x20;
    return NULL;
}
```

However, when I try to build, I get the following error:

error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
     AP_INIT_TAKE1("examplePath", example_set_path, NULL, ACCESS_CONF, "The path to whatever")

Am I missing out on something?

Thanks

Comment: who stole your `.c` file? :-)

Comment: Is it `C` code or `C++`? if `C++`, try adding cast to `const char *`, if `C`, use a `C` compiler.

Comment: do you include http_config.h?

Comment: change char *arg to const char *arg in tyour example_set_path declaration

Comment: @SouravGhosh  ...it is a .c file.

Comment: and your compiler is?

Comment: @Les ...Yes, I did include http_config.h

Comment: @SouravGhosh ..GCC Compiler

Comment: @SouravGhosh .I get the following error when I change to const char *arg: In function 'example_set_path' error: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror] config.path = arg;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third parameter of example_set_path should be `const char *arg`

```
#define AP_INIT_TAKE1 ( directive,  
  func,  
  mconfig,  
  where,  
  help    )     { directive, { .take1=func }, mconfig, where, TAKE1, help }
```

func is defined as...

```
const char *(*  take1 )(cmd_parms *parms, void *mconfig, const char *w)
```

Comment: `const char *example_set_enabled(cmd_parms *cmd, void *cfg, const char *arg)`...what it is now?

Comment: @Les...I get the following error when I change to const char *arg:  In function 'example_set_path'       error: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror]
     config.path = arg;

Comment: @ap6491 config.path probably takes a char *, so cast (char *)arg

Comment: Thank you @Les...config.path did take a char *. Casting (char *) arg fixed the error. Thank you.